# Can I miss web socket events if I reassign ws.onmessage?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am receiving data from a rest api via the function `callRestApi`, below. However, I receive updates on the rest data received via a websocket and I want to ensure that I dont miss anything. Therefore I start buffering websocket events prior to calling the rest endpoint. Having received the rest response I dispatch the buffered events and start dispatching anything new that is subsequently received, updating my copy of the data. But have I implemented this correctly? In particular, is there a risk that I could miss an event in the function startDispatchingEvents where I assign `ws.onmessage` a new value. I am using a redux dispatcher.

```
export const startBufferingEvents = () => {
    eventBuffer = [];
    ws.onmessage = msg => {
        eventBuffer.push(msg);
    }
};

export const startDispatchingEvents = (dispatcher) => {
    eventBuffer.forEach(evt => dispatcher(evt));
    ws.onmessage = evt => dispatcher(evt);
};


startEventBuffering()
    .then(()=>callRestApi())
    .then(restResponse=>dispatch(action(restResponse)))
    .then(()=>startDispatchingEvents((evt)=>eventDispatcher(dispatch, evt)))
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. All the code that is executed in JavaScript (assuming you're running this in a browser) is single-threaded. That means you cannot run into race conditions or any other concurrency issues. When the callback that replaces the value of `onmessage` is executed, access to the variable by, say, a websocket message, will wait (a.k.a. go into the event queue) until the callback execution finishes.

This might not be particularly related to the question, but if you are interested in learning a bit more about the event handling system of JS and the internals of the engine, I found this talk quite good: https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ